# how to checkout a remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I can see two remote branches in my local repository:

```
$ git branch -a
  remote/origin/master
  remote/origin/feature1
```

I actually have four branches in my remote repository. How can checkout the 3rd or 4th branch to my local?

I've tried lots of commands by searching internet, none of them worked for me.
I've not problem to get updates on master and feature1 branches from remote to local though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     url = <url>
>     fetch = +refs/heads/feature1:refs/remotes/origin/feature1
>     fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
> ```

is the source of the problem.  Here, you have instructed *your* Git that regardless of what branches exist in the Git over on `origin`, you want *your* Git to take and remember *only* `feature1` and `master`, which you will call `origin/feature1` and `origin/master`.

The default standard `fetch` setting for `origin`, if you don't change it, is:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If you had *this* setting, everything would just work automatically.

(The question then becomes: why did you stop using the standard, default setting, when you seem to want *behavior* provided *by* the standard, default setting?  **Edit:** and apparently the answer to that is: you didn't, Eclipse / EGit did.)

Comment: Ah-ha! I initially cloned my local repo through Eclipse/EGit by selecting the two branches I'd work on. I've been wondering for a long time why I have to re-clone if I ever wanted to switch to any other branch I haven't initially selected. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, so *you* didn't change the settings, but Eclipse / EGit did. I don't use these but it would be sensible for it to default to the standard setting.

Answer (score 0):

Your local repository may be out of date with respect to origin. To catch up, run

```
git fetch
```

Now you should see the other branches. If one of those branches is named `feature2`, then running

```
git checkout -b feature2 origin/feature2
```

or, with a recent git, simply

```
git checkout feature2
```

will checkout the branch and set up tracking in case you are collaborating with other developers.

Comment: I've tried exactly this, and the variation of "git fetch --all". The remote branches feature3 & feature4 still do not show up in "git branch -a"; and both "git checkout" failed to checkout feature3 or feature4.

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I have the following in the **config** file of my local git repo

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/feature1:refs/remotes/origin/feature1
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "feature1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature1
    rebase = false
```

After I add remote branch `feature2` to the `[remote "origin"]` section,

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/feature1:refs/remotes/origin/feature1
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/feature2:refs/remotes/origin/feature2
```

then run

```
git fetch --all
git branch -a
```

I see the remote `feature2` branch in the output.
And I can checkout `feature2` now.

Still have one question, how should I sync my local git repo's branch info with the remote repo without having to manually modify the `config` file?

Comment: Note: Rather than write this as an answer, it's better to edit the original question to add the extra information.